# Partial view is not getting loaded in main view though it is showing data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on asp.net MVC application and I am trying to bind the list data from the database. Though it is showing the count = 124.

I am calling the partial view from the index view when I debug it, it shows data and iterates through for each loop in view but not able to load it in view.

Index View:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Debug Log
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if (Model.DebugLogReportList != null)
            {
                @Html.Partial("pv_DebugLogReport", Model)
            }
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
</div>
```

Partial View:

Shown below in the screenshot with data count in the list,

[image]

And below is the controller calling my partial view...

```
 public ActionResult GetAll_DebugLogReport()
    {
       ..........

        return PartialView("pv_DebugLogReport", objLMT);
    }
```

Result screen below,

[image]

KIndly help me to know the reason.

Comment: Are you sure there is no css that is hiding the table (view the source of your page to check if the elements are generated)

Comment: The way you load your partial view it should load with the model data from the Index ActionResult. However you provide the Action method for your partial view. Are you sure you have understood the flow? Your action method GetAll_DebugLogReport shouldn't be triggered at all when you load your index

Comment: I think you are trying to get server side rendering of a table. This may look handy to you - https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching

Note - It is one time cost to implement it but you will have other benefits of it like ordering, searching etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke In view source, I see no element is generated

Answer (score 3):

I have seen you are trying to use **dataTable** in your view. For initial test, please remove your id **"dataTables-example"** from table and all corresponding **css and references** of dataTable.

Note: When using dataTable, if the no. of head rows **(i.e tr and th)** does not equal to body rows **(i.e tr and td)**,  then data will not be shown even though it is debugged.